# Visual Studio Performance Profiler provides blank results

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I run the performance profiler on my project in Visual Studio 2017 or 2015 the profiler doesn't seem to work. The application performance just as well as it normally does, and when profiling is stopped the report is empty.

I'm build a console app.

Here is a gif of me trying to profile the exe.

[http://i.imgur.com/lWpc8hw.gif](https://i.imgur.com/lWpc8hw.gif)

I get the same results when doing this with the project itself on a different device in VS 2017.

Why is this happening and how can I performance profile my application?

Comment: do you have a pdb file in the same folder as the exe?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain In some cases, yes. I've tried profiling from vs 2015 & 2017 on two different devices, the folder the pdb file dumps into is different depending. I've had success with VS2015 ~1/10th the time (~1 in 10 times the profiler seems to work)

Answer (score -1):

Disabling the antivirus worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21079418)

Comment: @RikSportel It solves the problem the question presents. Before disabling the antivirus the profiler gives empty results after disabling the antivirus the profiler gives a correct report.

The profiler is executed with administrative privileges and it seems the antivirus doesn't like that and prevent its CPU sampling from working.